# Can't execute the POST query with spring-boot. Whitelabel Error Page. 403 error while POST method execute

Tags: java, html, spring

I try to POST data from page to the controller, but I receive the unexpected issue.

First of all - while I do not tried the post method all works fine. I mean the mapping for the GET queries works correctly:

```java
@Controller
public class ProgramPage {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/program/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAddProgramPage(){
        //business logic - adding objects and mapping to the html page works correctly
    }
}
```

But after I added the simply POST form to the my HTML page and send data I receive the "Whitelabel Error Page".

- html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Add program</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/addProgram" method="post" class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-blue w3-margin w3-center"
      style="width: 50%">
    <div>
        <input class='w3-input' name='exerciseLine' type='text'/>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-margin">
        <input class="w3-button w3-blue" type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

- the POST body that I receive in the DevTools:

```json
{
    exerciseLine: test
}
```

- the controller:

```java
@Controller
public class ProgramPage {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addProgram", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testMethod(
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "-1") String exerciseLine
    ){
        System.out.println(); //breakpoint
        return "otherpage";
    }
}
```

**I execute the code in the debug mode with breakpoint in the `testMethod()` method - the code do not enter into it.**

## So, why I can't handle this POST method and how to fix it?

---

Additional info:

- application.properties:

```
#Database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

#Disable thymeleaf cashing
spring.template.cache = false;
```

- gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.hltr'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.30'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Do you need to return a ```ModelAndView``` rather than ```String```?

Comment: No matter, I tried both. And also I execute code in debug mode with a breakpoint - the code does not enter the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i notice your project import spring-boot-starter-security.The http status of 403 is auth error usually.

Comment: Thanks, but it is absolutely ununderstanding. I configured security to permit all pages (temporary): `.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()`
And haven't any problem to permit GET queries. Why the POST query is Forbidden?

Comment: This is a means designed to prevent CSRF attacks. If your service does not need to log in, you can turn it off(by .csrf().disable()).[link](href='https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0.0-M2/features/exploits/csrf.html#page-title)**spring security csrf**